# awesomium.dll crashes my WPF application on XP not Windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, crash, awesomium

I have created a WPF app that sometimes crashes with application error, modname = awesomium.dll

I have global catch and try blocks in my app.xaml.cs

```
    public App()
        : base()
    {
        this.Dispatcher.UnhandledException += OnDispatcherUnhandledException;
        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.UnhandledException += OnAppDomainUnhandledException;
    }
```

But the awesomuim.dll error seems to bypass this and crash the app regardless

Do we know how to either stop the random crashes on XP or add an application wide error catcher for Awesomium

Comment: I believe there was a change along the .NET versions. You might want to look into the 'UnhandledExceptionMode' in `Application` class IIRC.

Comment: thanks for that ill give it a go tommorow and report back#

Comment: Added as an answer, provided link, it helped me previously.

Comment: Have is this a x86 or x64 dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't recall the exact details, but look at [`Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setunhandledexceptionmode).